# SQL server 2005 Uploading image into database

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to upload an image into database, hence I added a uploadfile control and I am using an insert command like this :

```
INSERT INTO tab_employee(inter_sn, card_no, Tazkara_N, Tazkara_Vol, Tazkara_Page, Tazkara_SN, Name_emp, Fname_emp, GrandFatherName, Family_name, Gender, Birth_Day, Birth_Month, Birth_year, Marital_status, DOJ_Day, DOJ_Month, DOJ_Year, Position, Type_empl, Grade, Work_grade, Prof_level, Kadri_a, Act_code, ethic_gr, File_no, Birth_place, rem1, rem2, rem3,EngName,EngLastName,position_eng,**photo**) VALUES (@inter_sn, @card_no, @Tazkara_N, @Tazkara_Vol, @Tazkara_Page, @Tazkara_SN, @Name_emp, @Fname_emp, @GrandFatherName, @Family_name, @Gender, @Birth_Day, @Birth_Month, @Birth_year, @Marital_status, @DOJ_Day, @DOJ_Month, @DOJ_Year, @Position, @Type_empl, @Grade, @Work_grade, @Prof_level, @Kadri_a, @Act_code, @ethic_gr, @File_no, @Birth_place, @rem1, @rem2, @rem3,@EngName,@EngLastName,@position_eng,**@photo**)
```

after I browse my photo and trying to insert data into database I get this:

Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with image 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with image

can you help plz

Comment: What is the schema of the table you are trying to insert to?

Comment: i am using a function like this: public void insert_image(FileUpload file) { if (file.HasFile) ..... } . It throws NullReferenceException at if clause. I have an insert button that uses this code : FileUpload file = (FileUpload)this.FindControl("FleUpload");
        insert_image(file);

Answer (score 0):

In order to upload an image (insert/update) into database you need to define a controlParameter in  or/and  as follow:

```
<asp: ControlParameter Name="photo" ControlID = "FormView1$FileUpload1" DbType ="Binary"
    />
```

ControlID should be the full path of access to the control : here my fileupload control is inside a formview . and I am storing my image as Binary into the database (my db field type is Varbinary ) .